# Splitting a MS Word page into 3 horizontal sections

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-formatting, documents

I want to split a MS word page into 3 horizontal sections, such that the header and footer of the page do not repeat in the sections (this excludes putting 3 separate pages on one page). I have tried using tables, but they don't really work as they cannot be bound to one page (instead they flow onto the next page pages). As an added bonus, if the sections of two pages could link (i.e. the text from section 1 on page 1 continues into section 1 of page 2, and the text from section 2 of page 1 continues into section 2 of page 2 etc) I would very much appreciate of being made aware of how to do so!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is regarding rows not columns (that is why I said Horizontal section) sorry If I wasn't clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use text boxes that link to each other. In that case, text flows from one box to the next in the chain of links. So you could have three text boxes on each page, and make one chain from the top boxes, one from the middle boxes, and one from the bottom boxes.

It's probably only suitable for short documents.

To link two text boxes

- insert two text boxes
- click on the first box
- in the *Shape Format* tab of the ribbon, in the *Text* Group, click the *Create Link* button
- Click in the second box

If you now type some text in the first box, you will see that when it fills the box, it flows to the second text box.

Comment: Ok, the text box linking works, however I still need to know how to split the page into 3 separate horizontal areas (i.e. rows) (as before I can't use grids, unless you know a method of binding the **grid** to a page)

Comment: @Stalemate Well here, I just put three text boxes on the page where I want them. They can be "in line with text" or "floating" so it's not hard. If you need to replicate the layout page after page, you could save one as an Autotext. But not sure you have described *everything* that you need - if you want each page to be automatically laid out the same way, e.g. whenever you insert a page, this won't do that. Further, if you insert a page in the middle of the text, you will need to unlink each chain and relink. That's why it's only really much good for short documents.